# numbers and letters generator

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for ages for a generator that would generate letter, numbers and symbols. For example, using either javascript or php, it would print out:

```
a 

b 

c
```

etc. etc. etc.

```
aa

ab

ac
```

etc. etc. etc.

```
aab

aac

aad
```

etc. etc. etc.

I am horrible when it comes to any mathematical equations (I assume this would require Javascript as opposed to PHP).

Does anyone know of either a generator or a website explaining how to do this. I tried googling it, but the terms I use keep having some random generators popping up :/

**EDIT:** I have found this code. Any suggestions in implementing symbols with it, as well as mixing everything up? For example, aB1@

```
<?php
$i = 'a';
for ($n=0; $n<200; $n++) {
    echo ++$i . '<br/>'. "\n";
}
?>
```

I modified it to this so far :/ missing quite a few things I know.

1. -I have no clue how to add symbols in there.
2. -Nor how to mix all of it correctly.
3. -And I can't seem to start from A or 0

modified code

```
<?php
    $i = 'a';
    $m = '1';
    for ($n=0; $n<200; $n++) {
        echo ++$i . ++$m . '<br/>'. "\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to just use `for` loops and doesn't require any complicated math. For example:

```
var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz";

for(var a = 0; a < chars.length; a++) {
    for(var b = 0; b < chars.length; b++) {
        for(var c = 0; c < chars.length; c++) {
            console.log(chars[a] + chars[b] + chars[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/h7buU/ if you want to play with it

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could also create a recursive function that would achieve the same result and be more dynamic.

Comment: Damn, I viewed my firefox console, this is awesome! But, how can you show/echo those results? I am not at all familiar with the console.log aside that it shows up in the console in firefox.

Uhm, I just made it crash though -_- that is an infinite loop. Gotta make it stop I guess.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my post :/ 

Anyhow, let it be known that I am giving you a +1  (but since my rep is lower than 15, I am not authorized to do it).